# How did Osha pass through the wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Osha is a wildling, captured by Robb Stark and Theon Greyjoy when she and other wildlings try to kidnap Bran Stark.

How did she pass the wall from the north? Did she climb it? Did she pass through the tunnels? A different way?

Comment: IIRC, she didn't go through the wall, or over it, rather around it.

Comment: According to some of the Wikis, she got past the Wall via the Bay of Seals. I seem to recall that as well, but haven't found any official source (book or show transcript) that confirms this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go around The Wall in the West: The Wall stops at The Shadow Tower which is not all the way at the coast. It's mentioned that Wildlings sometimes slip through the hills on that side.
[image]

You can clearly see here that The Wall doesn't end at the coast. And even if it did, one could sail.